# How to use Launchd?

Tags: applescript, applications, script, launchd, automation

*(sorry if this is a bad question. I am new to apple coding)*

I want to run a .scpt file at a specific time, once a day, every day using `launchd` (if there is a better way please tell me) I am running macOS Catalina, and can make it a .app

How would I use `launchd` to run this? Please give me the complete code/steps to run this as I have no experience with Html/Css/Plist files.

Can somebody post a code template? I have never used PLIST files

Comment: Suggest you read the _manual pages_ for `launchd` and `launchd.plist` as well as for `launchctl`. In **Terminal**, use e.g. `man $command` where `$command` is one of the previously mentioned _commands_.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) In addition to waht @user3439894 recommended, you should also consider going the online guides [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) and [here](https://www.launchd.info). That should help you with your query or phrase a more focused question.

Comment: @user3439894 I didn't think of reading the manual page. Thanks!

Comment: @user3439894 how do you get out of the manual page in terminal?

Comment: Type the character `q` to get back to a command prompt. BTW if you just type the `$command` _name_ you can _right-click_ on it and select **Open man Page**, which will give you a better way to review and then just close the window normally.

Comment: @NimeshNeema do I need to make the .Scpt file into a .app?

Comment: RE: "Can somebody post a code template? I have never used PLIST files" -- There. is a sample .plist file at the end of the `launchd.plist` _manual page_!

Answer (score 2):

[`launchd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) manages the daemon(s) that ultimately run your job (in your case an scpt). But in a setup similar to the "[man behind the curtain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWyCCJ6B2WE)" in [The Wizard of Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)) you don't talk directly to `launchd`. Instead, you will prepare a `.plist` (property list) file that will be parsed by `launchctl`, and only then presented to `launchd` for action.

I did this (manually created a .plist file) a while ago, and wrote up a brief "how-to" that you can find on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/UsingLaunchdForSchedulingTasks.md). My experience was that writing an error-free `.plist` file from scratch is arcane and error-prone, but I'm sure one gets better with practice!

Note that this example was done on Mojave - not on Catalina. And as with various other things, Apple has made access to `launchd` (the man behind the curtain) more difficult in the name of security. In other words, the sample from my GitHub page runs successfully on Mojave, but it **will not** run on Catalina without hacking around Apple's more restrictive security measures.

Which brings me to the point of this: Instead of manually creating a `.plist` file, you may wish to consider using a third-party tool called [LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/). For Catalina, 'LaunchControl' now includes a "helper tool" called `fdautil` that simplifies cooperation with Apple's security mechanisms. I've used it successfully for two UserAgent jobs that run under `launchd` on Catalina.